# Slide Puzzle Solver In C

Tags: c

Trying to build a c sliding puzzle program from scratch. I figure I should use puzzle.h, puzzle.c, main.c for the files. I'd like to use a 4-nary tree structure, since there are a max of 4 moves possible. I have an idea for the structure below:

```
#ifndef PUZZLE_H
#define PUZZLE_H

struct Node{

       int Node *parent;
       int Node *next1;
       int Node *next2;
       int Node *next3;
       int Node *next4;
       int calc_heuristic;
       void     *pdata; }; Node

#endif
```

How and where do I code the array assignment to *pdata, in main, puzzle.c? Does this look correct?

Comment: What is `int Node` supposed to do?

Comment: i want the parent to point to the parent node, and the nextX to point to the next child nodes as the tree expands. Pdata points to the 3x3 array. I then calc the heuristic for each puzzle state, and sort the values for each state in descending order then select the next move from the lessor value of the heuristic.

Comment: It's pretty silly to propose a data structure with no algorithm. How is your solver going to work?

Comment: I have an idea for the algorithm, but I'm trying to figure out how to build the structure for the algorithms to work with. Silly to you maybe, but a person has to start somewhere. Now where would you start? Algorithm first, or structures first?

Comment: struct Node {
       struct Node *parent;
       struct Node *next1;
       struct Node *next2;
       struct Node *next3;
       struct Node *next4;
       int calc_heuristic;
       int puzzle[3][3]; }; Node

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
struct Node *parent;
struct Note *next1;
```

and so on, since you want pointers to the other Nodes in your tree.  If `pdata` is always going to be a 3x3 array, then you'll save yourself some hassle by declaring it as such, e.g.

```
int puzzleData[3][3];    // current state of the puzzle for this node
```

If the size of that array is not known at compile time, then you'll have to `malloc` memory for it at the same time that you `malloc` memory for the `Node` struct itself.

Comment: What should structure look like?

Comment: You've got it right in the comment that you added to the question, although the word `Node` after the last semicolon will give you a compiler error, and should be removed.